# How to share Videos to any app using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

**Issue**: What happens is after sharing the video when i launch the app to check the shared video it shows me error of "**Unable to import**" and "**The video is no longer available**".

**Android Version:** Oreo(8.0)

**Code**: I am trying with the following code to  share videos with other apps using intent:

```
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("video/*");

            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "abc");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "abcd");

            File imageFileToShare = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mygallery/" + "airp.mp4");

            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Main2Activity.this, "abc.dcf.fileprovider", imageFileToShare);

            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            share.setPackage("com.abc.in");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Message"));
```

The above code is working fine to share Images but its not working to share videos.

**What i have tried:** I have tried by sharing various file types like 3gp, mkv, mp4 but nothing is working out and I have also went  through various similar questions but no solution is working in case of videos.

Please help me with this issue and also if there is any alternate way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to your OnCreate

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

If that doesn't work for you,

Add Provider to Manifest by doing this

```
<provider
   android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
 </provider>
```

Remember to use `android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"` if you're using androidx

Create a file in xml directory (res/xml) and name provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Replace

`Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Main2Activity.this, "abc.dcf.fileprovider", imageFileToShare);`

with this

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Main2Activity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",imageFileToShare);
```

Comment: Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                m.invoke(null);

Comment: The above also worked, will you please explain why FileProvider is not working?

Comment: and please update your answer with a bit explanation so i can accept it as a answer

Comment: I've edited my answer with more details. You're now required to list your provider in manifest

Comment: The first solution is working for me but why not fileprovider?